# app refresh when typing routes in browser address bar angular 2

Tags: angular

I have defined routes in angular2 app.

```
    const appRoute:Routes = [
  {path:'',component:LoginComponent},
  {path:'about',component:AboutComponent},
  {path:'cart',component:CartAreaComponent},
  {path:'checkout',component:CheckoutComponent},
  {path:'register',component:RegisterComponent},
  {path:'verify',component:VerifyUserComponent},
  {path:'login',redirectTo:''}
]
```

Everyhting is working correctly when I change routes by using  tag.

But when I try to manually enter route in browser address bar. The app refreshes and go to home route.

e.g. `http://localhost:4200/verify` not working when typing directly in address bar. But working if done through some link in app.

Please help.

Comment: Can you post your full router class ,app.module and app.component

Comment: also what is your server, is it nglite? by usign ng serve??? Or some http server like nginx , apache etc?

Answer (score 0):

That can be because of html5history mode. If you are not using hash then you have ro configure your server to fallback to index.html of request routes not found. When you type manually adress and hit enter goes to server but when you click on links in application then angular take care of it on client side.